# What is the meaning of Eth Eyd'yam אֶת-עֶדְיָם in Shmoth (Exodus) 33.6?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, tefilin, parashat-ki-tisa

how would you translate Shmoth 33.6 אֶת-עֶדְיָם
ayd is witness so I'm guessing the literal is "witnesses" in the plural - some translate it as "ornaments" others as "finery" and others as "crowns" but I'm connecting it to "totafoth" - "in order that the Teaching of the L-RD may be in your mouth" Shmoth 13.9

Comment: the Kuzari, as reported in the Malbim connects it to tefillin

Comment: toddah rabbah - I posed the same question to a couple of  rabbis I know

Comment: in Shabbat 57b: "Rather, Rav Yehuda said in the name of Abaye: A totefet is an appuzainu, an ornament worn on the forehead."

Comment: there seems to be some (symbolic?) connection between tefillin and witnesses https://www.meaningfullife.com/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/2014/12/Yom_Kippur_2_5775.pdf

Comment: this isn't such a rare word. consider ותבאי בעדי עדיים or ותעד נזמה וחליתה

Comment: @Double AA you use several words please clarify

Comment: @rosends do you have a link to Malbim's comment on Kuzari? Where in Malbim's commentary can I find his comment to Kuzari? I looked on the Sefaria web site but they don't have his commentary on Shmoth! Perhaps you can quote Malbim directly; preferably translating it into English....

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.33.6?lang=bi&aliyot=1&p2=Malbim_on_Exodus.33.6.1&lang2=bi

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti. Notice that witness(es) has a complete different root than ornament(s). Witness(es) is from ayin-vav-dalet. Ornament(s) is from ayin-dalet-heh. That's why "ornaments", "finery" or even "jewelry" would be more precise in translation.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, JPS translates that phrase as "their ornaments".  Also, [here](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Concordance/5716.%D7%A2%D6%B6%D7%93%D6%B0%D7%99%D6%B8%D7%9D) is a link to a [concordance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance_(publishing)) for this word.  You can click on the links and see how they are explained or translated in each location.

The verse you quoted, [Shemos 33:6](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/33.6#e0n7), is actually going back on what had been said two verses prior, in [33:4](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/33.4#e0n7) (and really in 33:5 as well):

> וַיִּשְׁמַ֣ע הָעָ֗ם אֶת־הַדָּבָ֥ר הָרָ֛ע הַזֶּ֖ה וַיִּתְאַבָּ֑לוּ וְלֹא־שָׁ֛תוּ אִ֥ישׁ עֶדְי֖וֹ עָלָֽיו׃
>
> And when the people heard these evil tidings, they mourned; and no man did put on him his ornaments. (JPS translation)

The commentaries there give a variety of explanations, some of which are listed below:

- Rashi there says that this refers to crowns that the nation received when they said Naaseh Venishma (as per Talmud Bavli Maseches Shabbos 88a)
- Rashbam there suggests that it refers to types of jewelry
- Rabbi Avraham ben Harambam suggests it refers to weaponry/arms
- Chizkuni explains that this refers to the gold and silver vessels and clothing that they took out of Egypt with them
- Rabbeinu Bachya/Bechaye suggests that this refers to clothing (although that is more of a Kabbalistic explanation)
- Ralbag seems to understand this as relating to their Torah observance (although this does not seem to be a literal translation)
- Also likely not literally, Netziv understands it to be the "Jewish spirit"
- Malbim, as noted in the comments (and found [here in his commentary to 33:6](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Malbim/Shemot/33.6#m7e2n7)), understands it to refer to Tefillin.  He also quotes the Kuzari, who seems to understand it differently.  He additionally quotes various others who provide other suggestions.

Comment: I do not see how the Talmud's statement in Shabboth 88a can be reconciled with  Shmoth 33.4-6 (that the Angels came and removed their crowns) since Shmoth 33.6 states that Bnai Yisrael "stripped themselves of their ornaments"

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti added Malbim, and a source.  To answer according to Rashi, Bnai Yisrael stripped themselves of these crowns by committing this terrible sin.

Answer (score 0):

According to Rav Hirsch to 33:4, these "ornaments" are not specified, but in context with 13:16 they are tefillin, which in that occasion (33:6) they removed in sign of mourning.